# Is "there is no such software" a viable answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

I recently saw [an answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/7006) that says that "there is no such software" to do this thing. In this case, it properly describes why there can't be such software. in cases where it doesn't do that, should we let the answer stand?

My opinion is that such answers should stand if they are the only answer on the question (no other upvoted answers). However, if there is another upvoted answer on the question (or there clearly is software to perform what is being asked for), I think it's noise and should be removed.

I should mention that "it is not possible, and here's why" answers are permitted in certain cases on other sites like SO and SU.

What do you think?

Comment: @Gilles Sorry for posting a duplicate. That question didn't turn up in the related questions on the asking page.